# Ordering barchart in R with facet_wrap and two variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

my intention is to plot 2 charts "long term" and "very long term" unemployment using ggplot2 and facet_wrap.
I would like the order to be ascending by indic=="LTU" (top part of facet_wrap), so in the top chart "LU" and "MT" would not be on the right side. But I don't manage ggplot to order the bars properly. Any advice?

Reproducible example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(eurostat)

#Long-term unemployment by sex - quarterly average 
une_ltu_q <- get_eurostat("une_ltu_q", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)


df <- une_ltu_q %>% filter(age=="Y15-74",
                          geo %in% c("EU28", "BE","BG","CZ","DK","DE","EE","IE","EL","ES","FR","HR","IT","CY","LV","LT","LU","HU","MT","NL","AT","PL","PT","RO","SI","SK","FI","SE","UK"),
                          sex=="T",
                          s_adj=="SA",
                          time==max(une_ltu_q$time), 
                          unit=="PC_ACT")%>% 
        group_by(indic_em)%>% arrange()



ggplot(data=df, aes(x=reorder(geo, values), y=values))+
        geom_bar(stat = "identity", 
                 position = "dodge", 
                 show.legend = FALSE,
                 fill="steelblue")+
        geom_text(aes(label=values), vjust=-0.5, size=3.5)+
        facet_wrap(~indic_em, ncol=1, scales = "free")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`reorder` has a `FUN`ction argument, which you can use to change the ordering. By default, your example is ordered by the `mean` of the two values. But you could also take just the first value:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=reorder(geo, values, "[", 1), y=values))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", 
           position = "dodge", 
           show.legend = FALSE,
           fill="steelblue")+
  geom_text(aes(label=values), vjust=-0.5, size=3.5)+
  facet_wrap(~indic_em, ncol=1, scales = "free")
```

[image]

or the `sum`:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=reorder(geo, values, sum, na.rm=T), y=values))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", 
           position = "dodge", 
           show.legend = FALSE,
           fill="steelblue")+
  geom_text(aes(label=values), vjust=-0.5, size=3.5)+
  facet_wrap(~indic_em, ncol=1, scales = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please explain what exactly `"["` implies /means in `reorder` function?

Comment: @JustasMundeikis You're welcome. It's a shortcut for `reorder(geo, values, function(x) x[1])`. Square bracket is a function, see `?Extract`.

Answer (score 1):

Using the codes found at: https://github.com/dgrtwo/drlib/blob/master/R/reorder_within.R

We can use these functions to reorder within groups so each facet will have ascending bars. Below is the modified ggplot code integrating these functions.

```
reorder_within <- function(x, by, within, fun = mean, sep = "___", ...) {
  new_x <- paste(x, within, sep = sep)
  stats::reorder(new_x, by, FUN = fun)
}

scale_x_reordered <- function(..., sep = "___") {
  reg <- paste0(sep, ".+$")
  ggplot2::scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) gsub(reg, "", x), ...)
}


ggplot(data=df, aes(x=reorder_within(geo, values, indic_em), y=values))+
geom_col(stat = "identity", 
position = "dodge", 
show.legend = FALSE,
fill="steelblue")+
geom_text(aes(label=values), vjust=-0.5, size=3.5)+
scale_x_reordered()+
facet_wrap(~indic_em, ncol=1, scales = "free")
```